# Any advantages to Gnome's gslist over std::forward_list?

Tags: c++, c, stl, gnome, singly-linked-list

I'm updating some 1990's-era C code and converting it to C++. The original code relies heavily upon [Gnome's `gslist`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html) (singly-linked list). I'm finding `gslist` very cumbersome to integrate into my object-oriented code, so I'd really like to convert all those lists to C++ standard template library's `std::list` or `std::forward_list`.

Are there any good reasons (performance, portability, etc.) not to migrate to STL, and instead to stick with Gnome?

Comment: You may also consider simply using `std::vector` instead of `gslist`, depending on your needs.

Comment: @DietrichEpp : Yes, I've been looking at the code and `std::vector` appears to be a much cleaner, clearer, and simpler way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid replacing `gslist` with `std::list` as that would be changing a singly linked list into a doubly linked list. However, I would imagine that `std::forward_list` would perform similarly, but depending on the size of your objects you are storing in the `gslist` you might see a slight performance difference as well. This would be because of glib using a slice allocator instead of the standard allocator for `std::forward_list`.

If you aren't using C++ already, from a portability perspective, you might not want to go with the C++ solution, as not all platforms have a C++ compiler. However, if you can compile Gnome for a platform, I'd imagine it would ship with a decent C++ compiler as well.

One other thing that I could think of is adding the STL dependency could possibly increase executable size, if you aren't already using the STL. You might also see a slight increase in compile times.

The only true way to know is to do some profiling.

Comment: Thanks @Zack. Since this project is being built from the ground up in C++ and already uses STL in other components, I guess I'll go ahead and migrate away from `gslist`. Question answered to my satisfaction!